# Use CSS to target/select animateTransform element in SVG

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to select an animateTransform element within an inline SVG using CSS?

I am trying to manipulate certain attributes for the animateTransform element but can not seem to select it using CSS.  Can you assign it a class/ID to then reference with CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What distinguishing features does it have that you could select it by if it has no id?

Comment: Thing is I can assign it a class and/or id, reference it in the CSS, but do not know how to manipulate the elements attributes: begin, dur, from, to, repeatCount, etc.

Comment: Those attributes cannot be manipulated using CSS, only javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this:
If you use SVG (all formats) as a code (directly paste the code in html! don't use it as a file like in img>src or background-image), then you can manually set id and class to every child of svg, like
`<g>...</g>`
`<path>...</path>`
`<circle>...</circle>` and ...

you can change `fill`, `border weight` and other specific svg styles, but you are limited in some css styles, for example, for moving `<path>...</path>` elements you must use `translateX` and `translateY`! `margin` and `top, left, ...` doesn't work.

Comment: I got it working.  I did end up having to abandon using animateTransform and went with pure CSS3 transforms.